# Animation doesn't happen after animationend event

Tags: javascript, css, animation, page-lifecycle

I have one **div** element I want to animate **out** and **in** right after **out** by adding classes via js.

Animation **out** goes well, but after animationend event and removing **out** class and adding **in** class, the animation doesn't happen. I'm wondering why? I tried to use requestAnimationFrame, but it didn't work.

```js
(async function() {
  const boxEl = document.querySelector('.box');

  async function animationEnd(el) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      function handler() {
        // do something...
        resolve();
      }
      el.addEventListener('animationend', handler, { once: true });
    });
  }

  boxEl.classList.add('out');
  await animationEnd(boxEl);

  boxEl.classList.remove('out');
  boxEl.classList.add('in');
  await animationEnd(boxEl);
}());
```

```css
@keyframes anim {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }      
}

.in, .out {
  animation-name: anim;
  animation-duration: 2000ms;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
}
.out {
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

.box {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `animation-iteration-count: infinite;`.

```js
(async function() {
  const boxEl = document.querySelector('.box');

  async function animationEnd(el) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      function handler() {
        // do something...
        resolve();
      }
      el.addEventListener('animationend', handler, {
        once: true
      });
    });
  }

  boxEl.classList.add('out');
  await animationEnd(boxEl);

  boxEl.classList.remove('out');
  boxEl.classList.add('in');
  await animationEnd(boxEl);
}());
```

```css
@keyframes anim {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.in,
.out {
  animation-name: anim;
  animation-duration: 2000ms;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

.out {
  animation-direction: reverse;
}

.box {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work. I want the animation **in** to appear smoothly like **out**.
i.e. the box smoothly appeared and then smoothly disappeared